# How to make the solution of random math task become dynamic?

Tags: java, android

How do I make this piece of code generate to numbers which adds up to a sum of between 1 to 10? At the moment the solution is always 10 because of this
`int randomint2 = (10 - randomint1);`.

```
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    Random randomint = new Random();
    final int randomint1 = randomint.nextInt(max - min +1) + min;
    final int randomint2 = (10 - randomint1);

    final TextView displayrandomproblem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvrandomproblem);
    displayrandomproblem.setText(randomint1 + " + " + randomint2 + " = ");
```

Comment: final int randomint2 = randomint.nextInt(10 - randomint1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate `randomint2` depending on the value of `randomint1` to make sure the sum is between 1 and 10.

```
int min = 1;
int max = 9;//the maximum is 9 because the other number equals at least 1
randomint1 = randomint.nextInt(max - min) + min;

min = 1;
max = 10-randomint1; // maximum of the sum is 10
randomint2 = randomint.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the + 1

```
import java.util.Random;

class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 10;
        Random randomint = new Random();
        final int randomint1 = randomint.nextInt(max - min) + min;
        final int randomint2 = (10 - randomint1);
        System.out.println(randomint1 + " and " + randomint2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "randomint2" is not random at all. Your equation will add up to 10. That's not what the OP has asked for. Read the answer by @Heckel, and you will see that he's got the correct answer.